# Cannot load from assembly via nunit-console but works in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, macos, mono, nunit, xamarin-studio

I have a NUnit Library project was created in Xamarin Studio. Tests in this project runs perfectly via Run Item from the IDE.

However, via the console, it fails.

Executed in Mac OSX:
`nunit-console Test/bin/Debug/Test.dll`

Resulted in:

System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Am I loading the wrong System.dll somewhere?

Environment variables:
MONO_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/4.5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and spent several hours in exporting variables etc.
I still don't understand why the NUnit Console Runner has the conflict with .NET 4.5 when exporting the 4.5 mono framework.

Solved the problem by calling the predefined nunit-console Command of the mono framework located in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/nunit-console4 /my/test/project/Test.dll
```

The console still shows CLR 4.0 running on a 4.5 project but it works.

Please note that you maybe need to reboot or logout to eliminate any interfering exported variables.

Comment: Thanks. The reboot was the key. Tried nunit-console4 previously, but didn't remove MONO_PATH and then reboot before hand.